# React From Group input field is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I attached dropdown items to my form group input field (image below). When I add `onChange()` key in order to get its value, I cannot write anything to input field. But when I remove `onChange()` key, it is working, I am able to write anything, but I need to get the value of input field. Is there any other way than `onChange()` key or any solution? Thank you in advance :)
Here is the my code:

```
<Form.Control
        ref={ref}
        onClick={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          onClick(e);
        }}
        size="sm"
        type="text"
        className="search-or-jump shadow-none"
        placeholder="Search or jump to..."
        onChange={event => setSearchName(event.target.value)}
      />
      {children}
    </Form.Group>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add value attributes, like

```
<Form.Control
    ref={ref}
    onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onClick(e);
    }}
    size="sm"
    type="text"
    className="search-or-jump shadow-none"
    placeholder="Search or jump to..."
    value={searchName}
    onChange={event => setSearchName(event.target.value)}
/>
   {children}
</Form.Group>
```

Your code didn't have value attribule but you called 'value' on 'onChange' that why your code didn't work.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for you answer. It is working somehow but not properly. Now I am able to write just one letter then I have to put cursor to input field in order to write second letter. I cannot write 2 or more letters same time. Do you have any idea?